# SQL Counting up rows resulting from a sub query

Tags: sql

SELECT Count the rows that are in this query --> (SELECT Family FROM BIRD GROUP BY Family)
FROM BIRD

Every time I just try and count that sub query I get an error saying that there is more than one resulting value.
I'm not sure how to count up the rows resulting from a sub query, any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `select count(*) from (select family form bird group by family)`?

Comment: Thanks heaps, I'm new to sql and wasnt aware that you could "FROM" to something like that. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Others already did.  Don't worry, SQL becomes an art and you will get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put this sub-query in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   (SELECT   family
        FROM     bird
        GROUP BY family) t
```

But if you're just trying to get the number of different bird families you don't really need a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT family)
FROM   bird
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(*) as FamilyCount 
FROM (SELECT Family FROM BIRD
      GROUP BY Family) Families
```

`Count()` returns the number of items in a group. Read more [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try this for getting count, there is no need to sub-query for counting

```
select count( distinct family) from bird;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a count of the rows, let's have a go at this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT Family FROM BIRD GROUP BY Family)
```